# As in the response from the field server, with null values do not include these fields

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, openapi

I am writing a server part in Java, according to the **Api First** principle, a problem arose: how not to add empty fields to the response from the server.

Here is a yaml example

```
/external/v1/tariffs:
     get:
       tags:
         - external-tariffs-controller
       summary: Getting a tariff via mcc
       operationId: getTariffs
       parameters:
         - name: mcc
           in: query
           required: true
           schema:
             type: string
       responses:
         '200':
           description: Tariff received successfully
           content:
             application/json:
               schema:
                 type: array
                 items:
TariffsDto:
       type: object
       properties:
         rate:
           type: string
           description: Commission percentage rate
         minFeeSum:
           type: integer
           description: Minimum commission amount
         maxFeeSum:
           type: integer
           description: Maximum commission amount
       required:
         - rate
```

Purpose: from

```
[
     {
         "rate": "2.7",
         "minFeeSum": null,
         "maxFeeSum": null
     }
]
```

Easy to get

```
[
     {
         "rate": "2.7"
     }
]
```

I can’t delete an array, the answer needs to be in the array. Of the possible solutions that I found, there was the @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) annotation, but I can’t add that, because the class is generated automatically and I also added it to the spring configuration these fields:

```
jackson:
     default-property-inclusion: non_null
     serialization:
       write-null-map-values: false
       write-empty-json-arrays: false
```

my controller:

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TariffsController implements ExternalTariffsControllerApi {

    private final TariffsRepository tariffsRepository;
    private final TariffsDtoMapper tariffsDtoMapper;
    private final TariffsDto defaultTariff = new TariffsDto().rate("2.7");

    @Override
    public List<TariffsDto> getTariffs (@RequestParam("mcc") String mcc) {
        log.info("Getting tariffs list by mss={}", mcc);
        List<Tariff> tariffs = tariffsRepository.findTariffsByMcc(mcc);
        List<TariffsDto> tariffsDto = new ArrayList<>();
        if (!tariffs.isEmpty()) {
             tariffsDto = tariffs.stream()
                    .map(tariffsDtoMapper::map)
                    .toList();
            log.info("Found {} tariffs to be processed", tariffsDto.size());
        } else {
            tariffsDto.add(defaultTariff);
            log.info("Set default tariff");
        }
        return tariffsDto;
    }
}
```

didn't help either.
Help me please))

Comment: Are those jackson properties nested under [spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.json.spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion)?

Comment: yes, I just didn't indicate

Comment: How is the response content generated?  Is it using the `ObjectMapper` managed by Spring?

Comment: I don’t know, but I can show my controller in question

Comment: The project has ObjectMapper, they even do something with it, but I don’t use it and nothing worked

Comment: Try stepping through the return of that controller - at some point Spring will use a class to transform that `List<Tariff>` to json for the response.  See what Spring is using for that transformation.

Comment: Can you show me tutorial?) I'm uderstand, but can't do this

Comment: mapper just clean unuseble field. I forget say